# Check Return Value From Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have two stored procedures, ProcA and ProcB. I would like to ProcA to execute ProcB and have ProcB return an integer back to ProcA.

My preference would be use a `RETURN` statement in ProcB, but I'll use an `OUTPUT` parameter if that's my only choice.

Yes, there are similar questions on stackoverflow. But have yet to find a single one that will compile using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ProcB
(@pb int)
AS
RETURN 2* @pb /*Double it*/

GO

CREATE PROC dbo.ProcA
(@pa int)
AS

DECLARE @ret INT
EXEC @ret = dbo.ProcB @pb = @pa
SELECT @ret as doubled

GO

EXEC dbo.ProcA @pa = 10
```

Returns

```
doubled
-----------
20
```